# not able to run my pytest test cases here in jenkins even after running them in pycharm pytest

Tags: jenkins, pycharm, pytest

**my Error:**
[image: my error]
([full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nscMz.png))

**What i did:**

1. changed my paths in enviroment variables
2. installed pytest in cmd again

but still getting the same error

Comment: Sometimes restarting your Jenkins instance does the trick if it isn't recognizing a tool that you installed.